# How to validate unscoped records if default_scope is added in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, default-scope

I wan to validate all unscoped records. I have added default scope is there a way other than custom code.

Comment: What do you mean by "validate"? Validations are used to enforce the business logic when updating / creating records while scopes are used to query records from the database. Once you have loaded a record from the DB it does not know or care about which scope was used to fetch it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method called `unscoped`, that ignores the default scope of the class. For more info: https://prathamesh.tech/2019/07/15/how-to-not-use-unscope-in-rails/